# Как подключить в cmake opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, makefile

Я не хорошо знаю cmake и хотелось бы узнать как подключить opencv к проекту с cmake
У меня есть директория /home/OpenCv/ где есть собранная opencv
И так же установлена через pacman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прям на сайте OpenCV есть в разделе [документации](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html) готовый пример:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

От него и стройте свой файл.

Если же хочется использовать свою сборку (не рекомендованный для новичков способ), используйте этот ответ на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path)

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /home/OpenCv/)
```

P.S. `/home/OpenCv/` - очень странный каталог.

Comment: спасибо все работает вроде как
и можно вас спросить где хорошые уроки по опен св